# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to make a 3d plot using frames and an array.  In this code you can see that I have a system of equations that needs to be solved in order to get the "Z" value for my points. Each time through the for loop, I call in 2 values that are needed to solve the system and those 2 values are ultimately my "X" and "Y" values. Upon solving the system I pull one of the values and use it to find my "Z" value.

Running the code gives me

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

on line

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap = 'plasma')
```

What is the fix for this problem?

```
from pylab import *
from random import *
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

mdoth = 0.004916
Tinfhin = 334.75
cph = 1008
nsh = .598
hh= 86.68
Ash = .02
n=127
alpha = .00041427
rho = .002129
k=3.041
Le = .0025
Ae = .000001
re = rho * Le/Ae
Ke = k * Ae/Le
nsc = .674
hc = 87.68
Asc = .016
Tinfcin = 295.75
rL = re
mdotc = .004542
cpc = 1007

dframe = pd.read_csv("file name here")

plot(dframe['Sec'], dframe['TC (C)'], 'b-')
#annotate(xy=[818,72.25], s=&apos;First Entry&apos;)
xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Temperature (C)')
title("Exhaust")
show()

plot(dframe['Sec'], dframe['Amb (C)'], 'r-')
xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Temperature (C)')
title("Ambient")
show()

plot(dframe['Sec'], dframe['TC (C)'], 'b-', label = "Exhaust")
plot(dframe['Sec'], dframe['Amb (C)'], 'r-', label = "Ambient")
xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Temperature (C)')
legend()
show()

Tinfhin = dframe['TC (C)']
Tinfcin = dframe['Amb (C)']

X, Y = meshgrid(Tinfhin,Tinfcin)

powerArray = []

for index, row in dframe.iterrows():
    
    Tinfhin = row['TC (C)']
    Tinfcin = row['Amb (C)']
    
    def function(z):
        II = z[0]
        Qc = z[1]
        Qh = z[2]
        Tc = z[3]
        Th = z[4]
        Tinfcout = z[5]
        Tinfhout = z[6]
    
        F = np.empty((7))
        F[0] = mdoth * cph * (Tinfhin - Tinfhout) - Qh
        F[1] = nsh * hh * Ash * ((Tinfhin + Tinfhout)/2 - Th) - Qh
        F[2] = n * (alpha * II * Th - 1/2 * (II**2) * re + (Ke * (Th-Tc))) - Qh
        F[3] = n * (alpha * II * Tc + 1/2 * (II**2) * re + (Ke * (Th-Tc))) - Qc
        F[4] = nsc * hc * Asc * (Tc - (Tinfcin + Tinfcout)/2) - Qc
        F[5] = mdotc * cpc * (Tinfcin - Tinfcout) - Qc
        F[6] = (alpha * (Th - Tc))/(rL/n + re) - II
    
        return F

    guess = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
    z = fsolve(function, guess)
    power = n * z[0]**2 * rL
    powerArray.append(power)
    
Z = powerArray

ax = axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel("TC")
ax.set_ylabel("Ambient")
ax.set_zlabel("Voltage")
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap = 'plasma')
ax.view_init(0, 180)
```

Comment: That gives me ```ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.```

Comment: Maybe `ax.plot_surface(X, Y, np.array(Z).reshape(X.shape), ...)` ?